# A problem named reverse-bits from LeetCode

Tags: python

Why do the following two functions give different outputs?

```py
def reverseBits1(n):
    n = ((n & 0xaaaaaaaa) >> 1) | ((n & 0x55555555) << 1)
    n = ((n & 0xcccccccc) >> 2) | ((n & 0x33333333) << 2)
    n = ((n & 0xf0f0f0f0) >> 4) | ((n & 0x0f0f0f0f) << 4)
    n = ((n & 0xff00ff00) >> 8) | ((n & 0x00ff00ff) << 8)
    n = (n >> 16) | (n << 16)
    return n

def reverseBits2(n):
    n = (n >> 16) | (n << 16)
    n = ((n & 0xff00ff00) >> 8) | ((n & 0x00ff00ff) << 8)
    n = ((n & 0xf0f0f0f0) >> 4) | ((n & 0x0f0f0f0f) << 4)
    n = ((n & 0xcccccccc) >> 2) | ((n & 0x33333333) << 2)
    n = ((n & 0xaaaaaaaa) >> 1) | ((n & 0x55555555) << 1)
    return n

print(bin(reverseBits1(11111111111111111111111111111101)))
# The output is 0b1110001110001110111101100011100011100011100011
print(bin(reverseBits2(11111111111111111111111111111101)))
# 0b11111101111111110011100011100011
# And the second output is correct
```

I have searched online, but I can't find a good answer. Also I have tried to ask ChatGPT.

Comment: `11111111111111111111111111111101` is a decimal number, not a binary number. You need a `0b` prefix for binary numbers.

Comment: Because they're two different functions which do different things…!?

Comment: @interjay，but the second function works correctly.both function are the same input,and the contents of each function are also the same,how????

Comment: @deceze,serious bro?

Comment: I mean, yeah, sorry, it's the dumbest response ever, I know. But it's the plain fact. The functions do things in a different order. The result is different. … ‍♂️

Comment: @interjay, honestly,i've tried submit the first function in c,it work quite successful

Comment: @deceze, i've tried to submit the first function in c,it passed.And in python, it passed only when i submited the second function

Comment: The functions look like they're designed for 32-bit input. You're giving them a decimal number with 32 digits which makes it much more than 32 bits, so both will give the wrong answer.

Comment: @interjay, the second function gives the right answer bro,.it really bothers me a lot

Comment: Both answers are clearly not the bit reversal of the input so they're wrong. And Python is not C. For example, in C if you use 32-bit unsigned numbers then it will silently do operations module 2**32 but not in Python.

Comment: @interjay, i got it. thank you. i read it wrong. i'll try it again tomorrow